# Splitting a list to 5 lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, split

I'm trying to split a list to 5 lists. I searched on internet but the only thing I could find was how to split a list to `n` number of list, with the same amount of items in every list. 
This sadly doesn't solve my problem. What I want to do is split a list into 5 lists with different amounts of items.

- Lets say the list has 35 items, (this is not always 35, but it is
  never more then 45).
- I want to split it into:

  - a list containing items 1-5
  - a list containing items 5-13
  - a list containing items 13-20
  - a list containing items 20-27
  - and a list containing items 27-35

All of the things I saw where aimed at splitting a list into sub-lists of same sizes. So I was wondering if this is even possible.

Comment: How do you decide how many items would be in each list? That seems just random.

Comment: Do you know how to slice a list in Python?

Comment: Also, why are you repeating items in the new lists?

Comment: @DavidWestern was your query resolved?

Comment: Yes, I searched for the term list slicing. This question probably sounded really dumb, but if you don't know what something is called it can be really hard to search for answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using basic list slicing, like below:

```
In [1]: l = list(xrange(35))

In [2]: l[0:5], l[5:13], l[13:20], l[20:27], l[27:35]
Out[2]: 
([0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
 [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
 [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
 [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34])
```

I couldn't find any repeatable pattern between the numbers `1, 5, 13, 20, 27, 35`, but if there is one, you can easily calculate the nth and n+1th terms, to get the slices dynamically instead of hardcoding.

Also note, the indexes begin with 0 for a list in Python, and that when a slice of `list[x:y]` is done, the elements `list[x], list[x+1], .. list[y-1]` only are contained in the slice, and `list[y]` is not the part of final output.

Answer (score 0):

Below is to split in 500 chunks, we can use any number to chunk of 100 or 1000, instead of 500. Just replace and get going. Happy Coding!!

C# Code:

````
 public string OrdersListsplitAndProcess(List<OrderInfo> OrigOrdersList)
    {
        int rowscount = 0, totCount = OrigOrdersList.Count;
            int remainder = (totCount %500); int FinalQuotient = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDecimal(totCount / 500)));
            int thisQuotient = 0;
            List<OrderInfo> thisOrdersList = new List<OrderInfo>();
            for (int i = 0; i < totCount; i++)
            {
                thisOrdersList.Add(OrigOrdersList[i]);
                rowscount++;
                if (rowscount == 500 || (thisQuotient == FinalQuotient && rowscount == remainder))
                {
                    processOpenOrders(thisOrdersList);// CHUNCKED LIST
                    thisOrdersList.Clear(); // TO RESET and PREPARE FOR NEXT CHUNK
                    if (rowscount != remainder)
                        thisQuotient++;
                    rowscount = 0;
                }enter code here
            }
            return "finished successfully";
        }```
````